# Implement JUnit test for SNMP server and client

Tags: java, junit

I found very good example for SNMP server and SNMP client but I'm not sure how I can implement JUnit test into single test file:

```
public class SNMPClientTest
{
    @Test
    public void randomData()
    {
        SnmpTrap trap = new SnmpTrap("127.0.0.1",
            "1.3.6.1.4.1.2789.2005.1={s}WWW Server Has Been Restarted",
            2, "kschmidt", "MD5", "mysecretpass", "DES", "mypassphrase");
        trap.doTrap();
    }
}


public class SNMPServerTest
{
    @Test
    public void randomDatabaseData() throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        V3TrapReceiver v3 = new V3TrapReceiver("127.0.0.1", "kschmidt", "MD5",
            "mysecretpass", "DES", "mypassphrase");
        v3.listen();
    }
}
```

When I run the server I get message `Waiting for traps..` and I can't continue the JUnit test. But I can run them into 2 separate files.

How I can solve this? You can find the complete source code here: http://pastebin.com/zKEtXQmq

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to have both the client and the server running within the same test you can consider starting them as separate Threads within a single Test.

I normally try to avoid this because it does add some complexity and context management to the test.

Please note:

- This sample has not been tested, there may be tweaks that need to be made.  The gist of the handling of the additional threads should be about right.
- I did not verify anything for your tests, so all this does is run the server and then the client with no expectation of output or state.

  ```
  @Rule
  public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();
  @Rule
  public Timeout testTimeout = new Timeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  @Test
  public void testServerClientCommunication throws Exception () {
      final SnmpTrap trap = new SnmpTrap("127.0.0.1",
              "1.3.6.1.4.1.2789.2005.1={s}WWW Server Has Been Restarted",
              2, "kschmidt", "MD5", "mysecretpass", "DES", "mypassphrase");

      final V3TrapReceiver v3 = new V3TrapReceiver("127.0.0.1", "kschmidt", "MD5",
              "mysecretpass", "DES", "mypassphrase");

      Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                  while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                      v3.listen();
                  }
              } catch (Throwable th) {
                  //Exceptions thrown outside of the main Junit execution won't get propagated back to fail the test
                  //Use the ErrorCollector to maintain awareness
                  collector.addError(th);
              }
          }};
          //Create the Thread to handle the Server execution
          final Thread serverExecutor = new Thread(serverTask, "SNMP Server");
      /*
       * Create the client task and thread.
       */
      Runnable clientTask = new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                boolean clientIsDone = false;
                while (!clientIsDone) {
                      trap.doTrap();
                      //FIXME: Determine the state that matters.
                      clientIsDone = true;
                }

              } catch (Throwable th) {
                  //Exceptions thrown outside of the main Junit execution won't get propagated back to fail the test
                  //Use the ErrorCollector to maintain awareness
                  collector.addError(th);
              } 
          }};


          Thread clientExecutor = new Thread(clientTask, "SNMP Client");

          /*
           * Start the server first
           */
          //Don't hold the JVM if the server is not done.
          serverExecutor.setDaemon(true); 
          serverExecutor.start();

              /*
               * Now start the client.  Note that after the client traps successfully that it will interrupt the server thread.
               * The intent is that the interrupt will allow the server thread to die gracefully
               */
          clientExecutor.setDaemon(true);
          clientExecutor.start();

          //Since we off-threaded the tasks the test will consider itself 'done' unless we join with the client, which basically says
          //"Hold the current thread at this point until the other thread completes."
          clientExecutor.join();
  }
  ```

Comment: I get `Interrupted while waiting for traps: java.lang.InterruptedException`

Comment: If you did **not** get the state that you were expecting, then you may need to create a context-aware loop around 'trap.doTrap()' until the expected state is reached.   Drop the 'finally' block off the clientTask.  The call to interrupt was a courtesy for 'best path' for handling the two threads, but it doesn't play nicely with the errorCollector (I missed that - sorry).  As long as the serverExecutor is set as a daemon this shouldn't have an impact.

Answer (score 0):

Start the server in a method annotated with [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html). This will run before any other tests will be invoked.

Comment: I agree but the code execution hangs because there is sleep method(). How I can design the code is a way to run them both?

Comment: sleep method? can not find ... What I thought is that the `v3.listen();` spawns a thread (non-blocking) which will be running through out the "junit test session" and thus the client can send stuff to that server